# How to get data from serialized array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have serialized array:

```
a:3:{
    i:0;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:18:"Spetsifikatsioonid";s:2:"id";s:18:"spetsifikatsioonid";s:7:"content";s:132:"<ul> <li>Mõõtmed: 483 x 195 x 44 mm</li> </ul> <ul class="no-bullet" style="color: #444444;"> <li>Kaal: 2.9 kg</li> </ul>";}
    i:1;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Karbist leiad";s:2:"id";s:13:"karbist-leiad";s:7:"content";s:0:"";}
    i:2;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:5:"Video";s:2:"id";s:5:"video";s:7:"content";s:0:"";}}
```

How can I get data from "content"?

Comment: Start with [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize).

Comment: The serialized value has been corrupted in some way, try validate the string before doing unserialize.